# Show ApolloClient mutation result

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, mutation

This is my first time using Apollo and React so I'll try my best.

I have a GraphQl API from which I consume some data through ApolloClient mutations. The problem is that I don't know how to show the resulting information outside of the .result. I've tried to do so with a class that has a function to consume some data and a render to show it.

The mutation works and shows the data on the console but the page remains blank when the page is loaded, so the problem I've been stuck on is, how do I show this data?

Btw, if there's any advice on how to insert data from a form using this same mutation method I'd pretty much appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Component } from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import './modalSignUp.css';
import{header} from './Header.js';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ApolloProvider, Query, mutation } from "react-apollo";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql, useMutation } from '@apollo/client';


export const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4011/api',
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

client.mutate({
    mutation: gql`
      mutation signin{
      login(data:{
      username:"elasdfg",
      password:"12345678"}){
      id,roles,email,username}
  }
  `
}).then(result => console.log(result));


export class UserList extends Component {
    displayUsers() {
        console.log(this.result)
        var data = this.props.data;

        return data.login.map((user) => {
            return (
                <li>{user.email}</li>
            );
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <li>
                    {this.displayUsers()}
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')); 
root.render(<Header />);
```

**Mutation result**

[image]

I've tried to use a class to fetch the data given by the mutation and later render it in the component. I've also tried passing the result to a variable but I had no success with that.

I'm just expecting to see the data resulting from the mutation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should request data inside the component and then save it to the state.

```
export class UserList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      newData: null,
    };
    this.mutateData = this.mutateData.bind(this);
  }

  mutateData() {
    client
      .mutate({
        mutation: gql`
          mutation signin {
            login(data: { username: "elasdfg", password: "12345678" }) {
              id
              roles
              email
              username
            }
          }
        `,
      })
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ newData: result });
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mutateData();
  }

  render() {
    // do something with new data
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, I tried using it but when I try running it an error occurs and it says that the call to mutateData() in componentDidMount is not define, any idea why?

Comment: @AndresDavidOrtegaLobo Look at edited answer, pls

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that the other answer was accepted as the correct one, but a quick note for those who use **functional components**:

The `@apollo/client` `useMutation` hook gives you a "data" at the same moment that you create the mutate function:

From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/):

```
const [addTodo, { **data**, loading, error }] = useMutation(ADD_TODO);
```

Which has the *reactive* result of the last execution of the mutate function (in the exemple the `addTodo`), that way you may avoid using the `useState` to do that (and the manual binding of result and state).